# What is the most accurate way to test computational speed of a function in python

Tags: python, performance, time

Seen a few methods such as `time.perfcounter()`, `timeit.timeit()`, `time.time()` etc etc. However, which one is the most accurate?

Comment: it depends on where and how you want to implement it

Answer (score 2):

You can use a decorator to calculate the execution time of the function.
See the below example.

```
# importing libraries
import time
import math
 
# decorator to calculate duration
# taken by any function.
def calculate_time(func):
     
    # added arguments inside the inner1,
    # if function takes any arguments,
    # can be added like this.
    def inner1(*args, **kwargs):
 
        # storing time before function execution
        begin = time.time()
         
        func(*args, **kwargs)
 
        # storing time after function execution
        end = time.time()
        print("Total time taken in : ", func.__name__, end - begin)
 
    return inner1
 
 
 
# this can be added to any function present,
# in this case to calculate a factorial
@calculate_time
def factorial(num):
 
    # sleep 2 seconds because it takes very less time
    # so that you can see the actual difference
    time.sleep(2)
    print(math.factorial(num))
 
# calling the function.
factorial(10)
```

You apply this for any function.